# Exchange Online - Reporting on blocked users

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, reporting, windows-defender

There is a feature in Exchange Online which blocks users from being able to send email when they send too many emails in a time period. It usually triggers either when a user sends a load of emails via Mail Merge or when their account gets compromised and it's used to send a load of spam.

You can view which accounts have been blocked from sending either by going to the [Restricted Users](https://security.microsoft.com/restrictedusers) page in the Defender Security Portal or by running the `Get-BlockedSenderAddress` cmdlet in the Exchange Online EXO PowerShell Module.

The trouble is, these only show the users who are currently blocked. I have been asked by my employer to produce a report on who has **been** blocked in the last *n* days. I've looked at the reports in the Defender portal and there isn't one that does exactly that. I'm wondering if this kind of data is kept and if so, how I can extract it?

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it in Report > Email & collaboration > Compromised users. You can see the compromised(Suspicious or Restricted) users report in the last 90 days.
URL: https://security.microsoft.com/reports/CompromisedUsers

For more information about this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/view-email-security-reports?view=o365-worldwide#compromised-users-report

Comment: Awesome, thankyou. The reason I couldn't see it was because I hadn't been given the right role in PIM. I've now been given Security Admin and I can get to what I need.